# BindingSource error when filter is applied

Tags: vb.net, bindingsource

Can't figure out why I get this error after applying a filter to a BindingSource.

System.InvalidOperationException: 'DataBinding cannot find a row in the list that is suitable for all bindings.'

I am building a VB.Net WindowsForms app with two tables:
AptInfo which contains airport related data   and
RwyInfo which holds runway related data

Each table has a PK, AptID and RwyID, which are Identity fields in SQL.  Also, RwyInfo table has a field FK_AptID related to the AptID in the AptInfo table.
I fill these two tables in a dataset and create a BindingSource for each table.

I have various list controls and textbox controls and datepicker controls which are bound to the two BindingSource Objects.

If I don't filter the bindingsource for the RwyInfo table I don't get any errors - that is I can select any runway from any airport and all the databound controls update appropriately with the data for that runway.
The problem comes in when I apply a filter to the BindingSource for the RwyInfo table.

Of course, I only want to see the runways for the current airport and not all runways for every airport.

I tried to implement the filtering in the CurrentItemChanged event of the AptInfo binding source:

```
Private Sub bsrcAptInfo_CurrentItemChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bsrcAptInfo.CurrentItemChanged

    Dim oRV As DataRowView
    oRV = bsrcAptInfo.Current

    bsrcRwyInfo.Filter = "FK_AptID = " & oRV.Item("AptID").ToString
    Console.WriteLine("Filtered Rows found: " & bsrcRwyInfo.Count)

End Sub
```

I can confirm that the filter is applied to the BindingSource and the Count is correct.
However, after applying the filter, none of the databound controls updates based on the current item in the filtered list of runways.
If I try to select a different runway I get an error

System.InvalidOperationException: 'DataBinding cannot find a row in the list that is suitable for all bindings.'

I thought it might make a difference if the DataSource for the bindingSource were a DataView instead of a DataTable but that didn't make any difference for me.

Searching for that particular error message yielded one hint that perhaps NULL fields in the DataTable would cause a problem but after making sure all fields in the data table had data and there were no NULL fields in any of my RwyInfo records I still get this error.

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Regards

Comment: You don't need any code at all to filter a child table based on a parent selection. The data-binding can do it all for you, if you set it up correctly. Read [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?518065).

Comment: @jmcilhinney - WOW, this method should be easier to find, nevertheless,  the same error persists.  The runways for the first airport populate correctly but when I move to a different airport, all the runway databound controls do not update.  They continue to show the data from the first airport.  When I try selecting a different runway the same error pops up.  

System.InvalidOperationException: 'DataBinding cannot find a row in the list that is suitable for all bindings.' Would this error be the result of having a parent record that has no child records yet?

Comment: It sounds like your data-bindings are not set up correctly. I suggest that you clear all bindings in the designer and then set them up again from scratch. You can test after setting up each one so, if something breaks, you know exactly which one caused it.

Comment: *"Would this error be the result of having a parent record that has no child records yet"*. I was about to say "no" but then I wondered whether I'd ever tested that specific situation. I'm not sure that I have so I will do so and get back to you.

Comment: I notice that you say that you have at least one `DateTimePicker` control. How exactly are you binding that? Are you binding to the `Value` property and, if so, is the data in the relevant column nullable? If the answer is "yes" in both cases then that might be the problem, because there is no mapping between `DBNull.Value` and a valid `Date` by default.

Comment: EUREKA! the DateTimePicker was the problem. I was binding the 'Value' property to a column which is not nullable, however, there are cases where the Master record has no child records in the Detail table and so any time the Master hit one of those records all the databound controls for the Detail table did not update to null but kept the previously displayed values.  This situation will come up all the time in a data maintenance scenario when you add a new Master record and you haven't yet created any children in the Detail table.  Eliminate DateTimePicker binding solves it. Thanks!